# Is there a way to change the color of the " variable never used" underlines in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, preferences

(This isn't a programming question)

I don't want to disable the lines altogether, as they can be pretty helpful. The problem is I like to code on a dark background and the bright yellow underlines make it sort of hard to read sometimes. I want to change the color of the "variable is never used" underlines to a darker yellow, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > Warnings > change the color
```

Note that this will change the color of all warnings.